# segmentation fault in a C code

Tags: linux, permissions, memory, segmentation-fault, gpio

I have written a `C code` yesterday which works fine. Now I want to make some changes in the file, so I just copy this code in a new file. Compilation of new file is just fine, but when I try to run my executable file, I am getting `segmentation fault`. However my previous code is working. Initially I thought it's a permission issue so I change the permission of executable using `chmod 777`. But still I am getting `segmentation fault`. Here is my code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void pauseSec(int sec);
int main() {
        FILE *io,*iodir,*ioval,*iodir_S,*ioval_S,*io_S,*iodir_P,*ioval_P,*io_P;

        io = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w");
        fseek(io,0,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(io,"%d",15);
        fflush(io);
        iodir = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio15/direction", "w");
        fseek(iodir,0,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(iodir,"out");
        fflush(iodir);
        while(1)
        {
                fprintf(ioval,"%d",1);
                fflush(ioval);
                pauseSec(1);
                fprintf(ioval,"%d",0);
                fflush(ioval);
                pauseSec(1);
        }
        fclose(io);
        fclose(iodir);
        fclose(ioval);
        return 0;
}
void pauseSec(int sec) {
        time_t now,later;
        now = time(NULL);
        later = time(NULL);
        while((later - now) < (double)sec)
        later = time(NULL);
}
```

I wonder why same code is behaving differently when written in two different file. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Off-topic here. You should first compile your code with all warnings &  debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then learn to **use the debugger `gdb`**. BTW `ioval` is not initialized (you need to use `fopen` for it).

Comment: ... and your pauseSec is a busy wait loop which waits at 100% CPU which should be avoided. You may want to consider a `sleep` function like `usleep (unsigned int microseconds)` (needs `#include <unistd.h>`). And, yes, as @BasileStarynkevitch pointed out, `ioval` is uninitialised - points to NULL).

Comment: I comment pauseSec, still same issue

Comment: Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which is freely downloadable. You could use `sleep` instead of your `pauseSec` but you should **use the debugger**

Comment: And whenever you call a system or library function — ***especially*** one whose return value you are going to be using — you should check whether it succeeded.  This program is probably failing because you never set `ioval`, as other people have mentioned, but the fact that it doesn't check whether `io` or `iodir` is `NULL` is a fatal flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue, forget to initialize `ioval`. Correct code is here:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void pauseSec(int sec);
int main() {
        FILE *io,*iodir,*ioval,*iodir_S,*ioval_S,*io_S,*iodir_P,*ioval_P,*io_P;

        io = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w");
        fseek(io,0,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(io,"%d",15);
        fflush(io);

        iodir = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio15/direction", "w");
        fseek(iodir,0,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(iodir,"out");
        fflush(iodir);

        ioval = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio15/value", "w");

        while(1)
        {
                fprintf(ioval,"%d",1);
                fflush(ioval);
                pauseSec(1);
                fprintf(ioval,"%d",0);
                fflush(ioval);
                pauseSec(1);
        }
        fclose(io);
        fclose(iodir);
        fclose(ioval);
        return 0;
}
void pauseSec(int sec) {
        time_t now,later;
        now = time(NULL);
        later = time(NULL);
        while((later - now) < (double)sec)
        later = time(NULL);
}
```